# From Blogger to Wordpress: 301 Redirection for NGINX Server

Tags: wordpress, nginx, redirect, blogger

Maybe someone can help me. I want to migrate my Blog from Blogger to Wordpress. The importing of the files was no problem but now I have to set the redirection. Everything that I found was for Apache-Servers, but my new hoster has modern NGINX-Server and I can't change the .htaccess. So how I can do a working 301 redirection from Blogger to Wordpress?

Thank you very much!
Kathrin

Comment: did you have a custom domain name on blogger or a example.blogger.com subdomain?

Comment: Redirect 301 / https://example.com/

Comment: I have a custom domain for my blog!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In the server block**, you should set this statement:

```
include /etc/nginx/301s/somesite.conf;
```

In **/etc/nginx/301s/somesite.conf**, add this one:

```
location = /programs-services/ { return 301 https://www.somesite.com/; }
```

Please let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

hope this help you.

Add below mentioned code in .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com$ [OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com$
  RewriteRule (.*)$ http://www.newdomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: The new hosting is on NGinX-Server and so I can't make working changes in the .htaccess ... I have already asked the hoster therefore